# SQL Error on Audit Trail Insert after Scope_Identity()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to use a stored procedure to do an insert on a main table, then also insert that data into a historical data table. I don't want to use a trigger, but rather just do a simple insert of all columns into the history table.  I am getting this error, however.

"An explicit value for the identity column in table 'ipaudittrail' can only be specified when a column list is used and the IDENTITY_INSERT is on."

I imagine this has to do with Scope_Identity()? but I'm not well-versed in SQL, so I'm not really sure the best way to resolve this.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Insert Input
  (OpenedByName, Owner, Description, WorkOfDate)
Values 
  (@vOpenedByFirstName, @vOwner, @vDescription, @vWorkOfDate)

Set @vRecID = Scope_Identity()

Insert InputAuditTrail 
Select * 
  From Input 
 Where RecID = @vRecID

Select * 
  From Input     
 Where i.RecID = @vRecID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your audit trail table shouldn't have the identity property set on its `RecID` column as you don't want it to auto increment independently. You would need to alter the table definition to reflect that.

Having done that you could use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause for this.

```
Insert Input(OpenedByName,Owner,Description,WorkOfDate)
OUTPUT inserted.* INTO InputAuditTrail /*Inserts to Audit Table*/
OUTPUT inserted.* /*Returns to Client*/
Values (@vOpenedByFirstName,@vOwner,@vDescription,@vWorkOfDate)
```

Comment: +1 I had no idea you can split the `OUTPUT` to go both return *and* `INTO`. Neat!

Comment: Didn't know about Output.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert InputAuditTrail Select * From Input Where RecID = @vRecID
```

This returning a a number of columns and one of them is attempting to write into InputAuditTrail's identity column.

Replace the statement with

```
Insert InputAuditTrail(col1, col2, ./...) Select cola, colb, .... From Input Where RecID = @vRecID
```